# DBMS_LOCK how to find LOCKID by NAME

Tags: oracle

My task is to show for oracle forms user session id of some locked  object in oracle database. It is possible get from select  (l1.name is known value):

```
SELECT l2.SID
FROM   SYS.DBMS_LOCK_ALLOCATED l1,
       gv$lock                 l2
WHERE  l1.lockid = l2.ID1
AND    l1.name = 'OBJECT_NAME'
```

The problem is that  our oracle forms users have not access to the table SYS.DBMS_LOCK_ALLOCATED.  Package DBMS_LOCK has no function to find SYS.DBMS_LOCK_ALLOCATED.LOCKID by SYS.DBMS_LOCK_ALLOCATED.NAME.

Someone have ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: this might help https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53644/how-can-i-find-who-has-allocated-a-user-lock-via-dbms-lock

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to get lock status of object:

```
select     oracle_username || ' (' || s.osuser || ')' username
,  s.sid || ',' || s.serial# sess_id
,  owner || '.' || object_name object
,  object_type
,  decode( l.block
,       0, 'Not Blocking'
,       1, 'Blocking'
,       2, 'Global') status
,  decode(v.locked_mode
,       0, 'None'
,       1, 'Null'
,       2, 'Row-S (SS)'
,       3, 'Row-X (SX)'
,       4, 'Share'
,       5, 'S/Row-X (SSX)'
,       6, 'Exclusive', TO_CHAR(lmode)) mode_held
from       v$locked_object v
,  dba_objects d
,  v$lock l
,  v$session s
where      v.object_id = d.object_id
and        v.object_id = l.id1
and        v.session_id = s.sid
and d.object_name = '<My table>'
and d.owner = '<Owner>'
```

Note: I left `v$`-views but if You are using RAC and want to see all the instances here then just change `v$` on `gv$`.

You can check output of the query above after doing:

```
create table my_table as select 1 val from dual;
lock table my_table in exclusive mode;
```

P.S. Don't forget to hit `commit` to unlock `my_table`.